# Name of song in Episode 9 of No Game No Life at around 21:45?

Tags: music, no-game-no-life

What is the name of the song played in Episode 9 of *No Game No Life* at around 21:45? I can't seem to find this song anywhere.

Comment: Can you give some more details?
From where did you watch the episode?
What are the events happening at the time?

From the No Game No Life episode 9 I have acess to, at 21:45 all the people involved in the game start crying about how they were actually very scared the whole time.

The interesting song that plays in that episode during the game's turnabout when Shiro plays the winning moves is "All of you is all of me".

Comment: @Sigfried666 Yes it was that song you mentioned in the former. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably "Gray Sky" from the OST vol. 1, track 02

Answer (score -2):

If it is the end credit song of that episode it is:

### **Ai Kayano - Oracion**

Comment: Do you have a source for you answer? It would make your answer better. :)